# How to remove default bits from a byte array

Tags: java, arrays

My byte array output is showing unused bits (default) value as 0 in output.
How can I remove them from my result?

```
byte[] data=new byte[20];
int cl; 
try {
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("c:/abc.txt");

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((cl = fs.read(data,0,data.length)) != -1)
        os.write(data,0,cl);
    os.flush();
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
```

Here is the output from my code:

```
[104, 105, 32, 119, 101, 108, 99, 111, 109, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you don't mean this?

```
//...
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(os.toByteArray()));
```

You were printing the contents of the temporary array that you used to retrieve data from the file in byte blocks. By calling the `toByteArray` method (see [ByteArrayOutputStream#toByteArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29)) of your byte array stream, you may then get the pretended result, which is the whole contents of the file with the appropriate array size.

In a lesser matter, the zeros that you found in the data array were those defined when the array was created. They were not overwritten because the file size wasn't big enough to write all indices at least once. And quoting from [InputStream#read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

> In every case, elements b[0] through b[off] and elements b[off+len] through b[b.length-1] are unaffected.

Comment: @Dukeling That does not produce the same result. `ByteArrayOutputStream#toString` converts the buffer's contents into a string decoding bytes. In this case I assume we simply want to see the file's binary content.

Answer (score 0):

If only twenty bytes were written.

```
    if ((cl = fs.read(data,0,data.length)) != -1) {
        while (cl > 1 && data[cl - 1] == 0)
            --cl;
        os.write(data,0,cl);
    }
```

Though it seems the file is a text file, and is written with binary zeroes.
If you are sure always arrays of 20 bytes were written, and the trailing bytes were all 0, you could turn the first `if` again into a `while`.

Comment: It's entirely possible that `cl` is already the desired length. If so, the problem is with `Arrays.toString(data)`.

Comment: +1 dumb dumb dumb. Let's print in the while loop (`{}` not to forget), and print `cl` too. `Arrays.toString(Array.copyOfRange(data, 0, cl))`